# Access a Groovy variable from within bat step in Jenkins pipeline on windows slave

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

```
stage('Test Application'){
        agent { label 'windows' }
        steps{
                script{
                        def appName = "${params.ApplicationName}"
        println appName
        def appName1 = "\"Projects/$appName\""
        println appName1

        bat '''cd cognizant-intelligent-test-scripter-1.1-setup
                               run.bat -run -project_location appName1 -scenario "Scenario1" -testcase "TC2" -browser "IE" -standalone_report'''

              }
            }
```

I want to use the actual value of variable **appName1** in bat of groovy section but variable value in not getting replace ..see the command output while executing above stage in pipeline :

```
 Running on windows in C:\Jenkins\workspace\CI_Pipeline
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] script
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] echo
Billing
[Pipeline] echo
"Projects/Billing"
[Pipeline] bat
[CI_Pipeline] Running batch script

C:\Jenkins\workspace\CI_Pipeline>cd cognizant-intelligent-test-scripter-1.1-setup 

C:\Jenkins\workspace\CI_Pipeline\cognizant-intelligent-test-scripter-1.1-setup>run.bat -run -project_location appName1 -scenario "Scenario1" -testcase "TC2" -browser "IE" -standalone_report
```

Comment: How is this question related to the `batch-file` tag? I suggest you to remove such a tag...

Comment: Use triple double-quotes instead of single to define batch. Then you can use ${appName1} inside such string.

Answer (score 2):

Use triple double-quotes instead of single to define batch.

Triple-double-quoted strings behave like double-quoted strings, with the addition that they are multiline, like the triple-single-quoted strings. Neither double quotes nor single quotes need be escaped in triple-double-quoted strings.

````
bat """cd cognizant-intelligent-test-scripter-1.1-setup
                               run.bat -run -project_location appName1 -scenario "Scenario1" -testcase "TC2" -browser "IE" -standalone_report"""```
````

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same problem and it got resolved using triple double-quotes instead of single quotes. So, the query would look like:

```
bat """cd cognizant-intelligent-test-scripter-1.1-setup
                           run.bat -run -project_location ${appName1} -scenario "Scenario1" -testcase "TC2" -browser "IE" -standalone_report"""
```

Also, make sure to use the variables inside ${<var_name>}